# How to efficiently store pairs of numbers in a set?

Tags: python, set

In my program, I need to store pairs of numbers in range `[1, 10**5)` in a set and look them up many times. I can add them to the set as tuples:

```
seen = set()
seen.add((x, y))
(x, y) in seen  # True
```

but is there a more efficient way, e.g. using a numeric/string key that is a combination of two numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like combining numbers is the fastest method (about 2x faster than using tuples in my test):

```
seen = set()
seen.add(x*10**5+y)
x*10**5+y in seen  # True
```

P.S. to test it I used `%timeit` in ipython on these two functions:

```
def f1():
    seen = set()
    for x in range(1000):
        for y in range(1000):
            seen.add((x, y))
            assert (x, y) in seen    

def f2():
    seen = set()
    for x in range(1000):
        for y in range(1000):
            seen.add(x*10**5+y)
            assert x*10**5+y in seen
```

Results:

```
In [2]: %timeit f1()
466 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit f2()
254 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: my benchmark indicates the opposite. Can you publish your benchmark?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK OP's way is pretty much the most efficient. Sets hash their contents and that makes lookups have constant complexity, while tuple as the inner structure is small and fast, it is not wothwhile to use a frozenset (which is hashable and therefore can be an element of a set) for just a pair of values. So unless youhave a problem with the tuples being in order (not orderless), you are good.

Answer (score -1):

While combining the numbers together (x*10**5+y) gives better performance, it may be harder to debug issues in your set.  An alternative that is faster than tuple sets but a bit slower than numeric combinations would be to use a dictionary of sets:

```
def f3():
    seen = dict()
    for x in range(1000):
        for y in range(1000):
            seen.setdefault(x,set()).add(y)   # insert a new pair
            assert x in seen and y in seen[x] # check if pair in dictionary
```

This f3() function times at 0.284 sec vs f2() at 0.248 (so not a huge loss of performance).   It also gives you the added benefit of being able to easily list the y values of any given x.

**EDIT**

Using defaultdict does indeed make it faster. It's even faster than numeric combinations (0.126) and 4x faster than a set of tuples.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def f4():
    seen = defaultdict(set)
    for x in range(1000):
        for y in range(1000):
            seen[x].add(y)        # insert a new pair
            assert y in seen[x]   # check if pair in dictionary
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Replacing `setdefault()` with `defaultdict` makes this approach even faster.

Comment: It does. It also makes it simpler to test for presence in the "set"